# SQL Server stored procedure to insert/update data from one source to multiple destination tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my source table

```
Book | Employee | StartDate | EndDate
-------------------------------------
ABC     PQR       02/02/2014  06/06/2014
QWE     MNO       03/03/2014  07/07/2014
```

This is the DB schema, where this data should fit in...

`Book` table

```
BookID | BookName
-----------------
1        ABC
2        QWE
```

`Employee` table

```
EmployeeID | EmployeeName
-------------------------
1             PQR
2             MNO
```

`BookEmployee` table

```
BookID | EmployeeID | StartDate | EndDate
------------------------------------------
1         1           02/02/2014  06/06/2014
2         2           03/03/2014  07/07/2014
```

Note: if `Book` and `Employee` already exist in the `Book` and `Employee` tables, then we should not insert them, instead use their `ID` in the `BookEmployee` table

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Here is the basics of how this is done. You will have to do multiple inserts. The first one to Books. Then capture the BookID. Next insert into Employee and capture the EmployeeID. Finally you will insert into BookEmployee using the IDs from the previous inserts. Read up on the OUTPUT clause. You will need this.

Comment: I m stuck..not getting any Idea how to write a SQL proc. Can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do three queries.

```
INSERT INTO [Book] (BookName)
    SELECT DISTINCT Book
    FROM [Source]
    WHERE Book NOT IN (SELECT BookName FROM Book)

INSERT INTO [Employee] (EmployeeName)
    SELECT DISTINCT Employee
    FROM [Source]
    WHERE Employee NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeName FROM Employee)

INSERT INTO [BookEmployee] (BookID, EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDate)
    SELECT Book.ID, Employee.ID, Source.StartDate, Source.EndDate
    FROM [Source]
    INNER JOIN Book ON Book.BookName = Source.Book
    INNER JOIN Employee ON Employee.EmployeeName = Source.Employee
```

You could run those in a transaction if you're doing it a lot. You could also add in some `MERGE` behavior, but I wouldn't bother since you don't have anything more than one column to insert. I also didn't do anything as far as merging behavior is concerned for the last query, but I'm sure this will get you enough of a start to make it work.

But yeah, you won't be able to do it all "at once," per se, and even if you could, this way is significantly more readable than that would be.

Comment: Will this be a performance issue if I have 100k records or more in source table?

Comment: No more than there'd always be. There really isn't an alternative to doing it this way. It *should* be relatively fast, but it's no secret that lots of records make queries take longer. You could always try it and see how long it takes.